# External Iframe automatically sets itself to "overflow: hidden"

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, iframe

My app needs to use iframes to work with third party websites.
One of these websites, has a function that automatically sets its "overflow" to "hidden" when it detects itself being used as an iframe.

Is there a fix to this? I know in general if the iframe is not of same origin I shouldn't be able to change their css.

I would also like to know if there is a good reason to set "overflow: hidden" just because it is used as an iframe...

The app runs only on Samsung devices, using Chrome.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like they don't want you framing their site?

Comment: That's a very unlikely scenario, they are suppose to be one of business partners.

Comment: If they're your business partner, can't you ask them about the "good reason" yourself, and for a way to disable or work around it?

Comment: We did, and it will probably take very long for a reply (if they reply at all), which is why I'm here to ask around for fellow devs that may have ran into the same problem.

Comment: If they're detecting and messing with iframing, it's likely that's intentional. It's likely intentionally designed to be difficult or impossible to workaround for the same reasons. Many of us have run into the same problem; the answer is "yep, sites can block you from doing that".

Answer (score 0):

Their is nothing legitimate that you can do to fix this. The content of an iframe is sandboxed from the parent page by the security system in the browser.

As for why they do this, I expect they have another usecase where they find it useful, but it would be better to just turn scrolling off in the iframe element, than use overflow like this.